# Java Multi-threading Daemon thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, daemon, producer-consumer

I am working for a multithreaded application for a university coursework.
The scenario is a few elves working on producing presents and depositing them on a shared buffer where other elves consume the items to deliver them to children.
The program is a simulation of a working day which I manage to do using a clock Thread that clicks every few seconds. 
When the clock finishes, every thread is supposed to finish.
But what happens in my scenario is that a thread, or a group of threads do not allow the JVM to terminate after finishing the execution of main. I have tried finding similar problems on stack overflow and google. I have also tried using the deprecated function Thread.stop() to figure out which thread is causing the problem. 
I've come to the conclusion that the Thread that is being problematic is this one.

```
public void run() {
    while (!clock.isStopped()) {
        double fairChance;
        switch (turnTableID) {
            case 1:
                fairChance = Math.random();

                if (fairChance >= 0.5) {
                    //conveyor belt A Takes one of the two belts
                    BeltSemaphores(entryBuffer);
                } else {
                    BeltSemaphores(otherEntryBuffer);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //conveyor belt B
                fairChance = Math.random();
                if (fairChance >= 0.5) {
                    //conveyor belt B Takes one of the two belts
                    BeltSemaphores(entryBuffer);
                } else {
                    BeltSemaphores(otherEntryBuffer);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                BeltSemaphores(entryBuffer);
                break;
            case 4:
                BeltSemaphores(entryBuffer);
                break;
        }

    }
}

public void BeltSemaphores(ConveyorBelt belt) {
    try {
        //BELT SEMAPHORES
        belt.full.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        belt.mutex.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ///SACK SEMAPHORES
    if (sackOne != null && sackOne.SackID == belt.peek().getAgeGroup()) {
        SackSemaphores(sackOne, belt);
    } else if (sackTwo != null && sackTwo.SackID == belt.peek().getAgeGroup()) {
        SackSemaphores(sackTwo, belt);
    } else {
        try {
            exitBuffer.empty.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            exitBuffer.mutex.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Present a = belt.pop();
        exitBuffer.push(a);
        exitBuffer.mutex.release();
        exitBuffer.full.release();
    }

    //------------------
    belt.mutex.release();
    belt.empty.release();
}

public void SackSemaphores(Sack sack, ConveyorBelt belt) {
    try {
        sack.empty.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        sack.mutex.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sack.addToSack(consume(belt));

    sack.mutex.release();
    sack.full.release();
}
```

}

Do you know what is causing my problem? All the other threads share the `while(!clock.isStopped())` function and terminate gracefully.

Comment: if you are not sure which Thread is going to make a problem, please provide more, or better all Threads..., also please show the Error log, etc.

Comment: I am sure that the thread that is causing the problem is this one because once i call Thread.stop on this specific thread the program terminates

Comment: If an acquire() fails, you do a printStackTrace and continue anyhow?

Comment: For start, please **don't swallow InterruptedException**. Instead, restore interrupted status and throw some other exception, like this ```catch (InterruptedException ex) { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); throw new RuntimeException(ex); }```. For more details please look http://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/20/interrupted-exception.html and https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Comment: and only because a thread is closing 'gracefully' doesn't mean the error did definitely not started there...

Comment: @GerardH.Pille As far as I am aware the thread will wait for another thread to release it.

Comment: @TheJavaGuy-IvanMilosavljević Thanks for the articles, I wasnt aware that they should be handled that way. However in my Scenario I don't want this thread to be interrupted in anyway because I will lose the present that it already has in it. Would you still recommend to handle it and throw another exception?

Comment: @VariaP  Unless it is interrupted.  You should find that in the logs, but the thread ends up releasing a semaphore it didn't acquire (which is possible with Java).

Comment: Could you give us the code of acquire()? I assume that something there is blocking the thread.

Comment: You could also just use Java Visual VM and create a heap dump and look where the thread is stucking.

Comment: @Lars Finding a stuck thread in a HEAP dump?  Good luck with that ;-)  Oh, and the code for acquire is probably in the Jave source.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Java Visual VM lets you also browse through threads and the stack trace of the thread at the point you created the heap dump. Where do you see the code of acquire()? I don't see it.